# SQL - Reset row rank number every period of time

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know how to reset row rank number every 6 month. I always want to keep the first date record. Then count for 6 month more to get the next record I want. Any records in between I don't need. The start from this second record, count 6 month more to get the third record. The process just loops through until there are no qualified records.

Below are the SQL and the data.

SQL

```
SELECT ID, DATE FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID, DATE
```

The result is as follows,

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h2>Table esult</h2>


<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>DATE</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>4/28/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>5/27/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/27/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>7/21/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>8/18/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>9/22/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>10/14/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>11/18/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>12/16/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>1/20/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>2/24/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>3/24/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>5/5/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/26/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/26/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/27/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>8/11/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>9/8/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>10/6/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>10/6/2017</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

What I want to achieve is the result as follows,

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.highl {
    background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<h2>Table esult</h2>


<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
    <th>RANK</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highl">
    <td>123</td>
    <td>4/28/2016</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>5/27/2016</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/27/2016</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>7/21/2016</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>8/18/2016</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>9/22/2016</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>10/14/2016</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highl">
    <td>123</td>
    <td>11/18/2016</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>12/16/2016</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>1/20/2017</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>2/24/2017</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>3/24/2017</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>5/5/2017</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highl">
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/26/2017</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/26/2017</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>6/27/2017</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>8/11/2017</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>9/8/2017</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>10/6/2017</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>10/6/2017</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ID, DATE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) as rank
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID, DATE;
```

If you want to reset this every period of time, then include that information in the `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT ID, DATE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,
                                       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date),
                                       (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                          ORDER BY DATE
                         ) as rank
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID, DATE;
```